# How to get IViewLocalizer for a different page in net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization

I do have several pages used for different viewports. Like:

```
Page.cshtml
Page.amp.cshtml
Page.mobile.cstml
...
```

All the resources are identical in these pages but injecting IViewLocalizer uses different resource files:

```
Page.en.resx
Page.amp.en.resx
...
```

There is no point in duplication of resources string. And there is no point in moving such strings in a shared strings localizer. Creating a string localizer for each page is not the best idea in my mind as well. The idea is to keep Page.en.resx and to use it in Page.amp and Page.mobile. But I can't find a way to do that. The only thing I came up with is to use resources for the underlying C# class (PageModel) and to put all string into the ViewData. Or put the localizer into the model.

Is there any way to force loading resources for a different page?

Comment: `there is no point in moving such strings in a shared strings localizer.`Did you mean that you do not want a shared resource for the localization?Could you share the reason?

Comment: These strings using on this page only. And there are quite a few pages around. I don't like an idea of a single resource with all strings for all pages. It'll be hard to track all these strings when I decided to remove such a page.

Comment: Hi @sibvic,from the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#resource-file-naming),it said that resources are named for the full type name of their class minus the assembly name.So your requirement is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do that. I've replaced

```
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
```

with

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<PageModel> Localizer
```

And renamed the Page.en.resx to PageModel.en.resx (along with the move to the appropriate folder for its namespace.